# Distance versus displacement

Tags: calculus

> A particle moves along the curve $y = (\sqrt{x})^3$ in the first quadrant in such a way that its distance from the origin increases at the rate of $11$ units per second. The value of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ when $x=3$ is?

[image: graph of y]

In the given solution, they had taken the distance from the origin to a point on the curve (green segment) and used the distance formula from one point to another, but in my opinion that is not actually distance, that is displacement. Actual distance is the red segment from $(0, 0)$ to $(3, 3^{3/2}).$ Am I going in the right direction or do they mean displacement when they said distance?

The way I calculated $\frac{dx}{dt}$ gives an approximated and less value than the given solution which makes sense, like displacement $\le$ distance, so $x$ value is going to be lesser in distance than in displacement or equal when they cover the same magnitude $y$.

Please let me know if you would like to see my solution and the solution that I have doubt in.

P.S:- Thank you @Dave L. Renfro @DavidQuinn @ryang for the clarification.

Comment: The intended meaning is the "straight-line distance" between the point on the curve and the origin, not the "distance along the curve" between the point on the curve and the origin. Regarding "distance" and "displacement", if I thought these two words had different technical meanings, then I would think "displacement" would mean the distance along the curve. In any event, any intended technical distinction in the the meanings of "distance" and "displacement" should be made explicit by the author, although from what you've written, it sounds like YOU are the one making such a distinction.

Comment: Googling a bit, it seems "distance" and "displacement" have different technical meanings in physics, and the meanings you are attaching to these words agree with the technical meanings in physics. That said, in the calculus problem you are considering, "distance" is used in the straightforward mathematical sense -- the "straight line distance" between two points, the same meaning "distance" has when you studied school geometry and the same meaning "distance" has when you will (possibly later) study more advanced mathematics (e.g. metric spaces, etc.). **(continued)**

Comment: In mathematics one usually uses the phrase *arc length* for "distance along the curve". It is a bit unfortunate that there is such a [distinction between "distance" and "displacement" in physics](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/glossary/displacement-distance/) -- more so that I didn't immediately think of this, given that 40+ years ago I got as far as several graduate level physics courses.

Comment: Displacement relative to the origin is a vector - equivalent to position vector. Distance from the origin is the magnitude of the displacement vector. As @DaveL.Renfro has pointed out, this is not the same as distance along the curve, or distance travelled. I assume the given solution gives a value of $4$ for $\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Yes it is 4 and mine was approximately 3.95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > A particle moves along the curve $y = (\sqrt{x})^3$ in the first quadrant in such a way that its **$\color\red{\textbf{distance from the origin}}$** increases at the rate of $11$ units per second. The value of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ when $x=3$ is?

Writing them out unambiguously, do you see that these three expressions have different meanings?

- **$\color\red{\textbf{distance from the origin}}$**

  = magnitude of *position*

  = magnitude of *displacement* relative to the origin
- $\boldsymbol{P_1P_2}$

  = **distance between $\boldsymbol{P_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{P_2}$**

  = magnitude of *displacement* of $P_2$ relative to $P_1$
- **length of arc $\boldsymbol{P_1P_2}$**

  = **distance along the path between $\boldsymbol{P_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{P_2}$**

  = **distance travelled over $\boldsymbol{[t_1,t_2]}$**

So, the given solution, as described, is correct, and should, by the chain rule, finally give $$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\Bigg|_{x=3}=\dfrac{\mathrm d|\boldsymbol r|}{\mathrm dt}\Bigg|_{x=3}\div \dfrac{\mathrm d|\boldsymbol r|}{\mathrm dx}\Bigg|_{x=3}=4.$$

Related: [Deriving a particle's speed from its distance function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4690648/21813).