# Integrating the velocity vector

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, kinematics

If we integrate the velocity vector with respect to time, do we get the displacement vector or the position vector?

What I mean is that, do we integrate the velocity vector to get the displacement vector + constant, or can we say that position = integral of velocity vector + position at $(t=0)?$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I mean is that, do we integrate the velocity vector to get the displacement vector + constant, or can we say that the position = integral of velocity vector + position at 0

Comment: The displacement vector is the same thing as the position vector, right?

Comment: And clearly, $\mathbf r(t) = \int \mathbf v (t) \ dt + \mathbf r(0)$ (like you said).

Comment: You cannot assume that $c=0.$ You need to find $c$ using initial conditions. Often times, it turns out that $c=0,$ but this shouldn't be assumed as it isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: So is the integral of velocity equal to displacement or position then? (If v is vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we integrate the velocity vector with respect to time, do we get
> the displacement vector or the position vector?

Integrating velocity over a time **interval** gives the particle's **displacement across that period**.

> What I mean is that, do we integrate the velocity vector to get the
> displacement vector + constant,

The indefinite integral of velocity with respect to time gives the particle's position function up to an additive constant.

> or can we say that position = integral of velocity vector + position at $(t=0)?$

Not exactly. The integral $\displaystyle\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\boldsymbol v\,\mathrm dt$ of the velocity vector over the interval $[t_1,t_2]$ is the displacement $\vec{P_1P_2},$ i.e., the position vector of ${P_2}$ minus the position vector of $P_1.$

Read more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4690648/21813).